# Usage of @Override in a thread or onclicklistener in android programming

Tags: android, multithreading, onclick, overriding, runnable

I have a problem with `@Override`
I have seen examples in android programming that starts the `run()` block with @override in a thread:

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
          Toast.makeText(LOGOActivity.this, errorMessage,
                                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
 });
```

but in my eclipse the `@Override` annotation prompts an error , so I remove `@Override` then the error mark disappears.(when I hold my cursor on the error marked lines, it says remove `@Override`)
the same goes to "`OnClick`" in a listener.
How do you explain this? Am I right to remove `@Override`?

Regards

Comment: did you import Runnable ?

Comment: can You show us WHERE you have set runOnUiThread() and do You have something done like implemented the Runnable in Your activity?

Comment: @Blackbelt well, I have no error regarding not importing Runnable because no error is shown when override is removed.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs. I have written my runOnUiThread in my MainActivity-->inside a self-defined(imlemented) function, after 
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, LabActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(LabActivity.EXTRA_PHOTO_URI, uri);
        intent.putExtra(LabActivity.EXTRA_PHOTO_DATA_PATH,
                photoPath);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           
            public void run() {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

Comment: sorry, but I think we need to see the complete code.....something is missing, we can´t see any issue from that snippet....

Comment: @Blackbelt  I have no error regarding not importing Runnable because no error is shown when override is removed. Beside, I did not use Override  before "Onclick" (in setOnclickListener) in another application either and my app still worked.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs can you give me your email so that I can send you the whole code?

Comment: it´s better to post more here, because more poeple who can help with Your problem. You don´t need the complete code, just a little bit more that we can see the structure.....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs it is not actually my code I have downloaded that. The original code includes that override but when I write this annotation I am notified by an error. so I remove the annotation. I even tried to add these lines into my already working app, but it rejects the override annotation as well.

Comment: private void onTakePhotoFailed() {
     mIsMenuLocked = false;
        
     // Show an error message.
     final String errorMessage =
     getString(R.string.photo_error_message);

     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            
     public void run() {
     Toast.makeText(LOGOActivity.this, errorMessage,
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
      });
      }
      }

Comment: oh....then I think there is some wrong with Your imports. You have to check Your imports and especially the R. if it belongs to Your project....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs is each activity considered a separate UI thread?

Comment: import java.io.File;
     import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
     import java.io.FileOutputStream;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.util.List;
     import java.lang.Runnable;
     import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.content.Intent;;
     import android.net.Uri;
     import android.os.Build;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.os.Environment;
     import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
@Opiatefuchs

Comment: all activities running in the same UI thread...is the package declaration in that project equal to Your package?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs What if the two activities have different layouts(set content view), are they still in the same thread?.........................yep, i copied the code and then replaced the package name and deleted the override terms to eliminate the errors. It is noteworthy to say that I have seen on the net examples of thread without override too.

Comment: oh man.....I remember I had the same Problem in Eclipse long time ago. Importing a project sometimes give me this error too, but I can´t remember how I had fixed it.....

Comment: This has nothing to do with the layout. I recommend YOu to read about the processes and the lifecycle in the Android API. I know sometimes the API is hard to understand, but it´s exactly described there: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html  and  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: @Opiatefuchs here was the problem:my Eclipse was configured for compatibility with the Java 1.5 compiler, so I changed it to 1.6.To set the compiler for a single project, go to Project Properties ->Java Compiler.  Check "Enable project specific settings" and choose "Compiler compliance level" 1.6 or higher.

Comment: glad that it worked now :).....sometimes You don´t see the obvious thing at coding... :)